# Why in SQCD $R_{\psi}= R_{\phi}-1$?

Tags: supersymmetry

In SQCD = suspersymmetric QCD, in 4 dimensions and with one SUSY generator how do we determine the $R$-charge of the $U(1)_R$ symmetry of the various operators in a chiral supermultiplet? Say for $\mathcal{N}=1$ SQCD, where we have $R_{\psi}= R_{\phi}-1$. Why is this true? Is there a simple argument?

Of course, $\psi, \phi $ are the fermion and scalar component of the chiral superfield $\mathcal{Q}=(\phi, \psi, F)$. $F$ is the auxiliary field in order to make SUSY manifest off-shell and its $R$-charge is given as $R_F= R_{\phi}-2$.

In other words why $R_{\psi}= R_{\phi}-1$, $R_F= R_{\phi}-2$?

Comment: Please give context! What is SQCD? (I probably can guess it, but write it down, you aren't limited by space here!) What is the $R_\psi$, what is $\R_\phi$? Also, perhaps related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60337/50583

Comment: Well, SQCD in the physics literature stands for "super QCD". This is obvious from the fact I mention $\mathcal{N}=1$ which always denotes the number of susy generators. If someone answers my question it will obviously be someone who knows these stuff because they are standard notations. $\psi$ is the fermion components of the chiral supermultiplet, $\phi$ is the scalar component. A chiral supermultiplet can be written as $\mathcal{Q} = \{ \phi, \psi, F \}$ where $F$ is the auxiliary field with $R_F = R_{\phi - 2}$.

Comment: My point is that Stack Exchange questions should be written so that *others* can learn from them, not just so that you get *your* answer. So, put in a *bit* of effort, explain a bit about what you are doing, and what your notation is - make the question more accessible.

Comment: I will do so in the future!

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has answered this yet.. Anyways, I'm sure you've figured it out by now.